# Call a Flash AS3 function every 20 seconds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, increment

How do you set a function to increment in AS3 Flash.  I am trying to start the incremented function when my video starts and then run the same function every 20 seconds until the video stops.

something like:

```
    my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completePlay);
    my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, startPlay);

   function startPlay(){
       startInc();
       //OTHER items are started and set within this function that do not have to do with the incremented function.
    }


   function completePlay(){
       //This is where the startInc is stopped but not removed since it will be used again.

    }


     function startInc(){
          //This function should run every 20 seconds.
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User a timer around your player's VideoEvents.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.VideoEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class IncrementTimer extends Sprite
    {

        private var my_player:*;

        private var timer:Timer;

        public function IncrementTimer()
        {
            my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completePlay);
            my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, startPlay);
        }

        protected function startPlay(event:VideoEvent)
        {
            timer = new Timer(20000);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startInc);
            timer.start();
        }

        protected function completePlay(event:VideoEvent)
        {
            timer.reset();
        }

        protected function startInc(event:TimerEvent)
        {
            // called every 20-seconds
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I found the Timer Class 2 mins after posting. +1 and checked! I like the use of "timer.reset()" instead of "stop"

Answer (score 1):

```
var i:uint;

function startPlay(){
    i=setInterval(startInc, 20000);
}


function completePlay(){
    clearInterval(i);
}


function startInc(){
     //This function will run every 20 seconds.
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I thought this was removed but I can see it still exists in the flash.utils package. The documentation for it does recommend using a Timer instead though. Are there any benefits to this method?

Comment: Its plain simple, that's pretty much it. I guess both of them internally do the same thing. Easier than creating a timer, adding event listeners, and all of that